# Prove that given 2 regular expressions represent the same language

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

Is it possible to use regular expression identities to prove or disprove that the `RE1=0*(0+1)*0*` and `RE2=(0+1)*` represent the same language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

Clearly, $L(RE_2)=\Sigma^*$ ($\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ in this case), and obviously $L(RE_1)\subseteq \Sigma^*=L(RE_2)$ (since $RE_1$ contains only letters from $\Sigma$)

Now, we also have $L(RE_2)\subseteq L(RE_1)$, since concatenating with a language that contains $\epsilon$ is guaranteed to only expand the language. That is, for any $L$, and and $L'$ such that $\epsilon \in L'$, its clear why $L\subseteq LL'$. In this case, $L=L((0+1)^*)$ and $L'=L(0^*)$. Apply this twice from both sides and you will get that $L(RE_2)\subseteq L(RE_1)$.

Therefore $L(RE_1)\subseteq L(RE_2)\subseteq L(RE_1)$ and thus $L(RE_1)=L(RE_2)$

Comment: Is it possible to use regular expression identities to rewrite RE1? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/automata_theory/regular_sets.htm